# Django. How to get URL by its name?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I want to get url by name specified in `urls.py`.

Like `{% url 'some_name' %}` in template, but in Python.

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('admin_section/transactions/', AdminTransactionsView.as_view(), name='admin_transactions'),
    ...
]
```

I want to something like:

```
Input: url('admin_transactions')
Output: '/admin_section/transactions/'
```

I know about `django.urls.reverse` function, but its argument must be View, not url name

Comment: You are mistaken about the argument. As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse), "viewname can be a URL pattern name or the callable view object". Please include the specific error you get if this is not working.

Comment: reverse(url_name) works at the moment, i may have mistyped the name while post the question. Thanks for commenting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django has the [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) utility function for this.

Example from the docs:

given the following url:

```
from news import views

path('archive/', views.archive, name='news-archive')
```

you can use the following to reverse the URL:

```
from django.urls import reverse

reverse('news-archive')
```

The documentation goes further into function's use, so I suggest reading it.

Comment: Yep, i read that in the documentation before your answer, but thanks anyway.
This question can't be googled by direct request, so i hope it can help someone